# Spin 1 operator (I've seen like this form)

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In calculating of scattering amplitude of $\Sigma$ baryon (spin 1/2) and $\bar{D}^{*}$ (spin 1),
there the author defines spin 1 operator as

$\
O^{c}_{p,k}=i\varepsilon^{abc}\epsilon^*_{a}(p)\epsilon_{b}(k)$

$a,b,c={1,2,3}$
first $\varepsilon$ is antisymmetric tensor.
second and third $\epsilon$ is polarization vector.

I want to know why it is a spin 1 operator.
Could someone please teach it to me or tell me some reference?

Comment: which author, where?

Comment: https://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.103.116017  ※(23) says that.

Comment: I think your missing the point.  You want to make your post self contained as people will not read an entire paper to answer you specific question.  What is the part of this you do not understand?  Do you have trouble with transforming the polarization vectors?  Moreover it is better no change the body of your post rather than indicate additional information in comments as comments are subject to deletion.